# What happens if I don't specify targetFramework="4.0"?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, web-config

In my ASP.Net 4.0 web.config I had the following attribute:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0">
```

If I remove the targetFramework attribute, everything appears to carry on as normal.  Under what circumstances does this attribute help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Quote from the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400235(v=VS.100).aspx):

> Specifies the version of the .NET
>   Framework that the Web site targets.
>
> The default is Null.
>
> If this attribute is omitted, the
>   target version is determined by other
>   settings in the Web.config file and by
>   the IIS application pool that the Web
>   site is associated with. For more
>   information, see
>   CompilationSection.TargetFramework and
>   .NET Framework Multi-Targeting for
>   ASP.NET Web Projects.

So basically if your application pool in IIS targets ASP.NET 4.0 and you omit this attribute nothing happens => your site still uses .NET 4.0

Comment: So the user by default will not get the benefits of say 4.5?