# Problem with bin Deploying ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment, .net-4.0

I have problem with deploying my website to a server (which is not mine). I have one application that is running on this server and it is working (mvc 3, EF4). It was some time ago so I don´t know exactly what I changed to run it on that server but I think it was just adding referencies to bin folder. Now when I am trying on same server run my second app I did what is here: http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Bin-Deploy-ASPNET-MVC-3-Application-With-SQL-CE-40-Entity-Framework.aspx and It says problem with: "Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive." and the problem is on this line:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

I tried use google but every help that I found was with changing IIS but I am not administrator.

Thanks for help

Comment: Is your site running under a .Net 4 application pool?

Comment: What IIS version? have you run aspnet_regiis? .net "allowed" etc etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take out the `targetFramework="4.0"` bit as per [What happens if I don't specify targetFramework="4.0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2961130/27535)

It *could be* fixed in this patch as per [KB 2468871](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871), "Update for the .NET Framework 4", issue 9.

Comment: Thanks it helps but now I have problem this: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Comment: @Bibo: ask a new question then about "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.". Although, the clue is in the error. You built in for CLR 4 but this isn't on the server or enabled correctly.