# Problem with deploying ASP.NET MVC3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment, .net-4.0

This question is related to this: [Problem with bin Deploying ASP.NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901116/problem-with-bin-deploying-asp-net-mvc-3) I erase the line with `targetFramework="4.0"` but now I have another problem. It says:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

I can´t get access to IIS server because it is from provider of my hosting. It´s weird because one of my website is running on this server (MVC3 too) and now I am trying add next and it is not working. Thanks for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure your provider has `.NET 4.0` installed on their server?

It sounds like you are trying to run a `.NET 4.0` application on a server that only has `.NET 3.5` installed

Comment: I had one other website working on this server (MVC3, EF4 too) so I think there wouldn´t be problem with this. But I send email to my provider and he answer that he must changed something so I think you are right, thanks.