# Razor 2 with Web Pages 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages, razor-2

I cannot get Razor 2 view engine to work with my web pages project. I installed Web Matrix and everything but it's obvious that it's the Razor 1 engine that is used beacuse the tilde feature (href="~/style.css") is not working.

I've tried to modify my config file and to reference the Razor 2 dll files but it's still not working.

This is what my config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at System.Web.WebPages.dll in your bin folder, which version is there? 
(Mine is v2.0.20710.0 for instance)

Not sure why you would have an older version there if you are working with an up-to-date Webmatrix v2 Rel 2, but you can find the assemblies you are interested in here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies
```

***update based upon comment-thread:***

What Adrian Rosca eventually did to make this work in VS2012 was to reference all following assemblies and make them *"Copy Local"*:

System.Web.Razor.dll

System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll

System.Web.WebPages.dll

System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.

<s>***edit:***</s>

You might want to try adding the ***targetFramework="4.0"*** to your web.config compilation entry:

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

Check out the following SO post to read more on it and, depending on where you deploy your web application, whether or not it really matters to you:
 
[What happens if I don't specify targetFramework="4.0"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961130/what-happens-if-i-dont-specify-targetframework-4-0)

Comment: The dll in the bin is 2.0 but I can't get 2.0 specific features to work, so I guess it's still loading 1.0. I want to clarify that I'm not using MVC. Just plain Web Pages (.cshtml). Can you get the tilde feature to work? E.g. <link href="~/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Ok, just tested.. The new Razor 2 automatic tilde resolving works like a charm for me. Only settings I had in my web.config was this _<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />_ (Note the additional  ***targetFramework="4.0"***  compared to your config file)

Comment: Sorry. Still no luck. The targetFramework="4.0" made no difference. Started a new project from the "ASP.NET Empty Web Application" template in Visual Studio 2012 Express. Created an index.cshtml, a style.css and tried to load the style.css with a tilde resolving. Didn't work.

Comment: Not sure now... are you sure you have that style.css in your rootfolder? If you look at the source of your page in the browser.. do you still see the tilde in that link tags href attribute or a forward slash?

Comment: I still see the tilde in Firebug after page render so its clearly not parsed. I have the style.css in a folder named css. So the href is ~/css/style.css.

Comment: Tried to create an empty project with WebMatrix and that worked. But doing the same in VS 2012 Express doesn't work.

Comment: Great ! Now I wonder which dll you see in the VS 2012 Express projects bin folder? If it's the old version of System.Web.WebPages.dll, you can copy it from Webmatrix as I initially mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Now it works! The trick was to reference the following assemblies and make them "Copy Local": System.Web.Razor.dll, System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll, System.Web.WebPages.dll System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll. Which is pretty much what you said from the beginning... =) Many thanx for your help!

Comment: You should edit your answer with this since the targetframework is not really the solution here, but making the four assemblies above "Copy Local". Thanx again!

Comment: Just for future reference, I started a new project and it works if I only use these two assemblies as "Copy Local": System.Web.WebPages.dll and System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll.